# subset indexing in r

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a dataframe `ma`

it has a factor called `type`

`type` is comprised of the following factors:  `I210, I210plus, I210plusc, KV2c, KV2cplus`

I'd like to put some of these factors in a vector, say, `selected_types`

so, `selected_types<-c("I210plusc","KV2c")`

then, have this command subset the dataframe `ma`

```
ma1<-subset(ma, type==selected_types)
```

such that `ma1` would be a subset of `ma` consisting of only the observations that had

`type I210plusc and KV2c`

however, when I do this, the number of observations in the resulting dataframe `ma1` is less than the sum of the occurrences of the two types in `selected_types` from the original `ma`

Any ideas on what I'm doing incorrectly?

Thank you

Comment: Why not include dataframe df by `dput(df)` so that it would be easier to find out what's going on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I originally had this in a comment, but it's a bit lengthy, plus I wanted to add to it.  Here  some details on what's happening:

what you're doing with `==` is recycling your two length vector, so that every even row is compared to `"KV2c"`, and every odd one to `"I210plusc"`, so your final result will be the data frame of odd rows that are `"KV2c"` and even rows that are `"I210plusc"`.

An alternate solution that might make the issue clear is as follows:

```
subset(ma, type == selected_types[[1]] | type == selected_types[[2]])
```

Or, more gracefully:

```
subset(ma, type %in% selected_types)
```

The `%in%` operator returns a logical vector of same length as `type` with `TRUE` for every position in `type` that "is in" `selected_types` (hence the name of the operator).